# Wrapping both cpu-bound/io-bound long-running code into (async) Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, msmq

Consider the simple MVC5 controller:

```
public class DocumentsController {

    // ctor code is omitted

    [HttpPost, Route("api/documents/request/stamp={stamp}")]
    public ActionResult RequestDocuments(string stamp) {

        var documents = this.DocumentsRequestService.RequestByStamp(stamp);
        return new JsonResult(documents);
    }
}
```

The `DocumentsRequestService` does these things internally:

1. it sends a request to a dedicated *MSMQ-queue* (let's call it **M**) AND **synchronously** waits for an incoming message at the **M**'s response queue:

   ```
   using(var requestMessage = new Message()) {

       requestMessage.Body = documentStamp;
       requestMessage.Recoverable = true;
       requestMessage.Label = "request";
       requestMessage.ResponseQueue = this.requestedDocumentsResponseQueue;
       requestMessage.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(String) });

       // send request

       this.requestedDocumentsQueue.Send(requestMessage);

       // synchronously wait for response

       var responseMessage = this.requestedDocumentsResponseQueue.Receive();

       if(responseMessage.Label.EndsWith("success")) {
           return new DocumentsRequestResult(
               success: true,
               matches: parseMatchesList(responseMessage)
           );
       }

       return new DocumentsRequestResult(
           success: false,
           matches: Enumerable.Empty<DocumentsRequestMatch>()
       );
   }
   ```
2. the consumer (*Windows Service*) of that message makes a specific api call. By saying 'specific' I mean that we use a third-party means to do that. This call is synchronous and quite long. When the processing ends the consumer sends a response message to the requesting message's response queue.
3. when response arrives at the **M**'s response queue it's a time to parse and return the results to the controller.

From the end user's perspective this task should be blocking, or at least it should look like blocking.

As far as I understand running a **Task** makes use of parallelization. Whereas using the **async**-**await** pair makes the running task asynchronous. It could be helpful if several tasks would run in parallel.

Is it reasonable/possible to incorporate with **Tasking**/**Asynchrony** in my case? If yes, then where do I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "asynchrony" of a network call is transparent to the caller. It doesn't matter to the caller whether the implementation is synchronous or asynchronous. Put another way, from a client's perspective, it's *always* asynchronous.

For example, the HTTP client couldn't care less if `RequestDocuments` is synchronous or asynchronous; either way, the HTTP client will send a request and receive a response some time later (i.e., asynchronously).

Similarly, the HTTP web server doesn't care whether the Win32 service is implemented synchronously or asynchronously. It just knows that it puts a message on a queue and some time later (i.e., asynchronously) it gets a response message from the queue.

> As far as I understand running a Task makes use of parallelization. Whereas using the async-await pair makes the running task asynchronous.

Sort of. `Task` can be used for either asynchronous or parallel code, a fact that has caused much confusion. However, Task Parallel Library constructs such as `Parallel` and PLINQ are firmly in the parallel (non-asynchronous) world.

> It could be helpful if several tasks would run in parallel.

I believe "concurrently" is the appropriate term here.

First, note that ASP.NET gives you a considerable amount of concurrency for free. If you want to make *each request* internally concurrent, then you can do so fairly easily via `Task.WhenAll`. For example, you can change your `DocumentsRequestService` call to be asynchronous (assuming your message queue API supports async calls):

```
using(var requestMessage = new Message()) {
  ...

  // send request
  await this.requestedDocumentsQueue.SendAsync(requestMessage);

  // asynchronously wait for response
  var responseMessage = await this.requestedDocumentsResponseQueue.ReceiveAsync();

  ...
}
```

Then you can call it multiple times simultaneously from a single controller action as such:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RequestDocuments(string stamp1, string stamp2) {
  var task1 = this.DocumentsRequestService.RequestByStampAsync(stamp1);
  var task2 = this.DocumentsRequestService.RequestByStampAsync(stamp2);
  var documents = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
  return new JsonResult(documents);
}
```